# Rails 5 development application.js file not updating even after restarting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

Changes in application.js file not reflecting, since every time rails pick file from public/assets folder.
Here is my **application.js** file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ./inner/jquery.min.js
//= require ./inner/sidebar-nav.min.js
//= require ./inner/jquery.slimscroll.js
//= require ./inner/waves.js
//= require ./inner/mask.js
//= require ./inner/footable-init.js
//= require ./inner/jquery.waypoints.js
//= require ./inner/jquery.counterup.min.js
//= require ./inner/raphael-min.js
//= require ./inner/morris.js
//= require ./inner/morris-data.js
//= require ./inner/owl.carousel.min.js
//= require ./inner/owl.custom.js

//= require ./inner/custom.min.js
//= require ./inner/dashboard1.js
```

I tried:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I also tried in **development.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after running rake `rake assets:precompile` it will load assets from `public/assets` folder so you need to delete `public/assets` and restart your server also delete your cache `rm -rf tmp/cache` from your project directory.

Comment: This is still not working, public/assets directory isn't present still application-xxxxxxx.js is loading from public/assets folder.

Comment: @Rohit: "still application-xxxxxxx.js is loading from public/assets" - that's not possible, is it? Something doesn't match here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes its still loading from public/assets directory.
Is there any solution? thanks in advance..

Comment: @Rohit: how do you know that? The file _isn't there_, what's being loaded then?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In Browsers network console, the file appears to be loaded.

Comment: Browser might have its own cached copy with a higher TTL. Try loading in incognito?